# No association bonus for Apple account

Tags: support, association, association-bonus

I didn't get 100 association rep for Apple site https://apple.stackexchange.com/

The associations were already set, I cleared and reapplied from within the site and also cleared and reapplied from an account that already has more than 200 rep, but it hasn't applied.

I've also tried logging out and back in again as suggested in another post.

For every other site I've joined the bonus happens automatically when I join, not sure why it hasn't happened in this case.

My profile on Apple site: https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1434/xiaohouzi79

Comment: Just to be clear, you already had an account and you cleared and re-associated?  Had you already associated prior to having 200 rep?  I'm pretty sure if you already associate once you can't just reassociate after you eclipse 200 rep on your other account to get a 100 rep bonus on the associated account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did get the association bonus, but you also gave up 100 rep to place a bounty on [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/3519/revisions).

Comment: Srry about that, I haven't actively used the site for a long time and forgot about that original question.